# JSX: Conditional statement within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to understand how to incorporate conditional statements within JSX.  I have an array of objects that I'm mapping to a select box.  I want to exclude items that include the substring "threshold" in indicator.name.

So I can't use a ternary operator, because there's no "or" item.  But I can't figure out how to include an if statement within this map.  Whatever I try I get an error.

```js
<select
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  onChange={e => setIndicator(e.currentTarget.value)}
  disabled={loading}
>
  <option key='' value=''>
    Select
  </option>
  {indicatorList.map(indicator => (
    <option key={indicator.name} value={indicator.name}>
      {indicator.label}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: `indicatorList.filter(v=>v.includes("threshold")).map(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter then map:

```
<select
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  onChange={e => setIndicator(e.currentTarget.value)}
  disabled={loading}
>
  <option key='' value=''>
    Select
  </option>
  {indicatorList.filter(indicator=>indicator.name.includes('threshold')).map(indicator => (
    <option key={indicator.name} value={indicator.name}>
      {indicator.label}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Or return null:

```
<select
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  onChange={e => setIndicator(e.currentTarget.value)}
  disabled={loading}
>
  <option key='' value=''>
    Select
  </option>
  {indicatorList.map(indicator => (
    indicator.name.includes('threshold')?<option key={indicator.name} value={indicator.name}>:nul
      {indicator.label}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: thanks! Filtering and then mapping is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the filter method to filter out "threshold". This would return the array you are expecting to have inside JSX